# SpringBoot @Scheduled and @Transactional is required to be in separate class?

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, scheduled-tasks

I read that It is not a good practice to put `@Scheduled` and `@Transactional` annotation together because of the Spring default AOP implementation. (proxy classes etc.)

I have decided to try it by myself and I created a very short app for testing but surprisingly my code works when I put these things together and also when I created a separated Schedule service for the annotation.

```
@Entity
class AEntity(
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aEntity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = [CascadeType.REMOVE])
        var bEntities: MutableSet<BEntity>? = null,
        @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)

@Entity
class BEntity(
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "a_entity_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        var aEntity: AEntity,
        @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null
)
```

Service:

```
@Service
class AService(val aRepository: ARepository) {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    @Transactional
    fun test() {
        val aEntity = aRepository.findOneById(1)
        aEntity?.bEntities?.forEach {
            println(it.id)
        }
    }
}
```

You can reach my full project from [here](https://github.com/eszikk/springboot_demo)